# Crear un Controlador para sentencias de INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Busco insertar los valores de los campos de una sentencia con bindValue() pero no funciona pero si lo hago de la manera individual si funciona porque sera ?

**Este metodo funciona**

```
 public function Create($data)
    {

        $this->db->Insert('users',array(
            'login' => 'text',
            'password' => 'text',
            'rol' =>'Admin'
        ) );

     }


public function Insert($table,$data)
    {

      $sth = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO users (`login`,`password`,`rol`) 
        VALUES (:login,:password,:rol)');


        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $sth->bindValue(":$key",$value);

            //Si Imprimo el var_dump me da true la insercion de los valores
            //var_dump($sth->bindValue(":$key",$value) );
            // echo "<br><br>";
        }

        // Si imprimo este var_dump me da true el execute
        var_dump($sth->execute());
        $sth->execute();
        die;



    }
```

**Este metodo no Funciona**

```
     public function Create($data)
    {

        $this->db->Insert('users',array(
            'login' => 'text',
            'password' => 'text',
            'rol' =>'Admin'
        ) );

     }


public function Insert($table,$data)
    {
        ksort($data);

        // Con implode se busca reescribir la sentencia sql para la insercion
        $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($data) );
        $fielValues = ':'.implode(', :', array_keys($data) );

//----------------------------------------------------------------
        // Para que quede asi :
        /* $sth = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO users (`login`,`password`,`rol`) 
            VALUES (:login,:password,:rol)'); */
//----------------------------------------------------------------

        $sth = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO $table(`'.$fieldNames.'`) VALUES ('.$fielValues.')');

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $sth->bindValue(":$key",$value);

            //Si Imprimo el var_dump me da true la insercion de los valores
            //var_dump($sth->bindValue(":$key",$value) );
            // echo "<br><br>";
        }

        // Si imprimo este var_dump me da **FALSE** el execute
        var_dump($sth->execute());
        $sth->execute();
        die;



    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo diría que el tema está en el prepared statement, si imprimes var_dump( 'INSERT INTO $table(`'.$fieldNames.'`) VALUES ('.$fielValues.')') como te sale?

Comment: Me imprime esto = $sth = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO users (`login`,`password`,`rol`) 
   VALUES (:login,:password,:rol)');

Comment: Y luego se supone que el bindValue le asigna valor a las coincidencias a las que tengan esto ( : )

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solucion y fue que debi colocar en la sentencia; comillas simples la llamar la tabla ( `'.$tabla.'` ) de este modo la varible table es reconocida como variable y asi inserta su valor... Debi colocar esto  ** `'.$table.'` ** Incluyend las comillas simples diagonales

```
`$sth = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.$fieldNames.'`) VALUES ('.$fielValues.')');`
```